# vue.congfig.js not able to share javascript variable on scss variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I am working on dynamic color on my project. So i was succeed to store variable on env and passed on vue.config.js in order to render scss color variable from env variable. but i got into problem when i had to render color value from api since api send color variable as a object. so is it possible to pass object on scss **prependData** as a object ?

**Existing code passed from env:**
I am using vuejs 2 and i am adding these code on **vue.config.js.**

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `$VUE_APP_PRIMARY:${process.env.VUE_APP_PRIMARY};
            $VUE_APP_FOOTER_PRIMARY_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_FOOTER_PRIMARY_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_CARD_BANDAGE_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BANDAGE_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_FONT_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_FONT_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_NAV_PRIMARY_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_NAV_PRIMARY_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_DARK_BTN:${process.env.VUE_APP_DARK_BTN};
            $VUE_APP_DARK_BTN_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_DARK_BTN_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN:${process.env.VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN};
            $VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR:${process.env.VUE_APP_ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR};
            $VUE_APP_FONT_FAMILY:${process.env.VUE_APP_FONT_FAMILY};
            $VUE_APP_FONT_HEADER:${process.env.VUE_APP_FONT_HEADER};
            $VUE_APP_BACKGROUND:${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKGROUND};
            $VUE_APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE:${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE};
            $VUE_APP_CHOOSE_CATEGORY:${process.env.VUE_APP_CHOOSE_CATEGORY};
            $VUE_APP_PLACEHOLDER:${process.env.VUE_APP_PLACEHOLDER};
            $VUE_APP_BTN:${process.env.VUE_APP_BTN};
            $VUE_APP_FOOTER_LINK:${process.env.VUE_APP_FOOTER_LINK};
            $VUE_APP_MULTIPLE_TAG:${process.env.VUE_APP_MULTIPLE_TAG};
            $VUE_APP_CART_BTN_BACKGROUND:${process.env.VUE_APP_CART_BTN_BACKGROUND};
            $VUE_APP_CART_BTN:${process.env.VUE_APP_CART_BTN};
            $VUE_APP_ORDER_INFO_CARD:${process.env.VUE_APP_ORDER_INFO_CARD};
            $VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE_BACKGROUND:${process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE_BACKGROUND};
            $VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE:${process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE};
            $VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_HOVER:${process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_HOVER};
           `
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Code i want but compiler send error:**

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: {
          '$VUE_APP_FOOTER_PRIMARY_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_FOOTER_PRIMARY_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_NAV_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_CARD_BANDAGE_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BANDAGE_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_FONT_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_TOP_HEADER_FONT_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_NAV_PRIMARY_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_NAV_PRIMARY_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_DARK_BTN': process.env.VUE_APP_DARK_BTN,
          '$VUE_APP_DARK_BTN_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_DARK_BTN_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN': process.env.VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN,
          '$VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_BRAND_BTN_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR': process.env.VUE_APP_ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR,
          '$VUE_APP_FONT_FAMILY': process.env.VUE_APP_FONT_FAMILY,
          '$VUE_APP_FONT_HEADER': process.env.VUE_APP_FONT_HEADER,
          '$VUE_APP_BACKGROUND': process.env.VUE_APP_BACKGROUND,
          '$VUE_APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE': process.env.VUE_APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE,
          '$VUE_APP_CHOOSE_CATEGORY': process.env.VUE_APP_CHOOSE_CATEGORY,
          '$VUE_APP_PLACEHOLDER': process.env.VUE_APP_PLACEHOLDER,
          '$VUE_APP_BTN': process.env.VUE_APP_BTN,
          '$VUE_APP_FOOTER_LINK': process.env.VUE_APP_FOOTER_LINK,
          '$VUE_APP_MULTIPLE_TAG': process.env.VUE_APP_MULTIPLE_TAG,
          '$VUE_APP_CART_BTN_BACKGROUND': process.env.VUE_APP_CART_BTN_BACKGROUND,
          '$VUE_APP_CART_BTN': process.env.VUE_APP_CART_BTN,
          '$VUE_APP_ORDER_INFO_CARD': process.env.VUE_APP_ORDER_INFO_CARD,
          '$VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE_BACKGROUND': process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE_BACKGROUND,
          '$VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE': process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_DELETE,
          '$VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_HOVER': process.env.VUE_APP_CARD_BTN_HOVER
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**
[Npm issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtFsy.png)
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying the second block when the first one works for you? The error message indicates that `prependData` can only be a string or a function, so an object would not work.

Comment: its because i want to set color from api since in env every time i had to set it for changes. so is there any way so that prependData accept object ?

Comment: Why can't you just create the string from the object that you get from the API like in the first example?

Comment: Yes its possible to create string from object its my second solution if i wonot be able to passed object but i just want to passed direclty as a object. since i don`t want to write extra code every time when there is change in object key from api.